# Parameterized select query returns empty lines

Tags: c#, sql-injection

I have recently started looking into SQL injection so do excuse me if I am making a obvious mistake. I have a query which returns certain fields from the database. I am trying to parameterize it now so I can avoid SQL injection. My code is below

```
protected string UserInfo()
{
    string UsrName = User.Identity.Name;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Common.ConnectionString))
    {
        UserDetail det = new UserDetail();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName=@fn,LastName=@ln,MobileNumber=@mn,EmailAddress=@ea from Users,OtherInfo where OTID = USERID AND UserName=@UserName"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", UsrName); // Works correctly for this
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn" det.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln" det.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mn" det.FirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ea" det.FirstName);
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                reader.Read();
                info.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                info.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                info.TelNum = reader["MobileNumber"].ToString();
                info.Email = reader["EmailAddress"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `UserDetail` has the following properties:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string TelNum { get; set; }
```

But it just seems to return `null` values? Does anyone know where I'm going wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't mean to pass in the empty values from your `UserDetail` object. You are effectively passing in the `null` values from `UserDetail` as value for the columns your query outputs.

Try to remove the parameters in the `select` part, remove them from the command, and try again:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FirstName,LastName,MobileNumber,EmailAddress from Users,OtherInfo where OTID = USERID AND UserName=@UserName"))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", UsrName); // Works correctly for this
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            info.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
            info.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
            info.TelNum = reader["MobileNumber"].ToString();
            info.Email = reader["EmailAddress"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that make the query vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: No. The fields come from the database, which is safe. You only have to worry about what goes in (like `UserName` in your code), not out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and further tip on sql injection :)